# why this jquery isnot selecting?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

sorry for asking this simple question, but i am stuck, why is this jquery not taking the value, it is alerting empty message.

my jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $('dt').on('click',function(){
     alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

my html:

```
<dl>
<dt>test</dt>
<dd>- test</dd>
</dl>
```

i am expecting it to alert the `test` message. but it is alerting without message. `$(this).val()` must be right, i think. 
thanks for help and guidance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.val() is for input elements, you need to use .text()

```
alert($(this).text());

or

alert($(this).html()); // Careful, since it will include markup (obviously)
```

Comment: great Mike, i didnot know that.

Answer (score 3):

It is because `val()` relates to the `value` property of an input field.  `<dt>` is not an input field.  Try doing

```
$(function(){
  $('dt').on('click',function(){
     alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes.. absolutely I just used text here as that is all he had in his example and would yield the same result here as `html()`.  If you had HTML tags within the element you are calling this method on and wanted to maintain that HTML content, `html()` would be most appropriate.